# safest git merge option on (very) long lived branches

Tags: git, merge

Suppose we have to deal with two very long lived branches B and C that share the same origin A.

Suppose also that branch B has sometimes been merged in C, and many conflicts have been resolved in the wrong way.

In this situation, both B and C diverge in many ways, and doing a `git merge` of B in C or the opposite does not work well: many divergences do not figure as conflicts because perhaps they have been resolved in the past or for some other git reasons.

Is there any `git merge` option that can signal every single difference as conflict? even the previous resolved ones?

(The safest thing to do is to do a diff of B and C, manually compare each file and take only the right changes. This works, but the downside is that you lose the git history.)

Comment: You should revert that bad merge commit, instead of merging on error state.

Comment: trust me, I would do that. It is a divergence of many years with thousands of commits. It is that the problem.

Comment: You have not explained what the goal is. What are these branches even for? What do you ideally want them to look like? The purpose of Git is not branches or even history but state: the idea is that the current commit should represent a desirable state. If the current state is undesirable, fix it and commit the desirable state. Don't be hypnotized by the past.

Comment: Good point: the goal. The goal is to have a version D that has will represent the single source of truth, containing both features of B, features of C and also code that is different in B and C.  The goal is to fix this state taking the "right" contributes from both branch B and C. Ideally I would need a command that applies all changes of C in B and signal all the differences between B and C as conflicts.